# Benchmarking a webserver using AB won't parse images

Tags: apache-2.2, php, benchmark, ab

I'm using AB to benchmark one of my servers but it doesn't seem to parse the images at all.

If I use ...

```
ab http://foobar.com/image1.jpg
```

It works brilliantly, but if I use ...

```
ab http://foobar.com/index.php
```

It doesn't request the images at all (I'm reading log output), index.php contains a small benchmark script as well as ...

```
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

If I browse index.php manually in a browser it requests the image, any ideas?

Best Regards

Comment: I just read that AB doesn't work in the same way as a person browsing a site, so I guess this works as intended, so another question would be: can I mimic a real browser? In other words, fetch all images in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this sort of load testing. ab is great as a quick test to check how your code manages under load but lacks some features.

JMeter has a tick box to tell it to request referenced resources for HTTP requests(such as images, css etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a desktop application, must be CLI.

Comment: I believe JMeter can run as a daemon on a server (though I have never used this functionality myself). You may find it easier to develop the test plan on a GUI machine then upload the resultant JMX file to the server version of JMeter to run (as opposed to writing the JMX file by hand).

Comment: JMeter works, but it seems way too complicated for a benchmarking tool. The UI is clearly geared towards testing and QA. It also crashed on my 32G desktop when I tried 1000 simultaneous connections which should only take 1G at 1MB per page. I guess it's only suitable for benchmarking sites hosted on a Raspberry Pi lol